# Cartoon where child is tried by fishes for fishing

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Sometime back around 1956-1961 I watched many older English language cartoons on television in the USA.

Among others, I remember two cartoons which seemed to be part of the same series.

One cartoon involved the character Little Lulu and had the song "Would you like to swing on a star".

The other, which I think may have also involved Little Lulu, had a child being tried by a fish court for the crime of fishing. I remember a scene where a widow fish testified, singing "once upon a time we happy, life was simply grand, but that was a long time ago, before my husband was canned", holding up a can of fish.

So I looked up the [Little Lulu theatrical short cartoons on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Lulu#Short_films), and found "A Bout with a Trout", October 30, 1947, described as having fish and having the song "Swing on a Star".

I just watched "A Bout with a Trout" online and it has the song "Swing on a Star", but no scene where a fish jury tries a child for fishing.

There are 25 other cartoons in the Little Lulu series, and none of their descriptions involve a child being tried by a fish jury.

So possibly it was a a cartoon in a different series.

I don't remember if there was a real fish jury in the cartoon or if the child just dreamed it, so I don't know ho wmuch the cartoon is on topic here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is [*The Seapreme Court*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0152346/?ref_=m_tt_urv).

Not Little Lulu, but rather Little Audrey, tried by a jury of sardines.

> Little Audrey, while fishing, falls to the bottom of the sea, where she encounters all types of sea-life and then is arrested by the local fish-constable. She is tried by a jury of sardines who find her guilty, and she is sentenced to the 'eelectric chair." She makes an escape attempt, and wakes up to find it has all been a dream. She has a nibble on her fishing line and reels in a small fish, which she quickly returns to the water.

Comment: I just watched "The Seapreme Court"   and it is pretty much like the cartoon I remember.